# Azure DSC extention. How to use additional items in a archive

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc

I'm trying to use DSC extension for Azure VM. I have created zip archive with main PS file, and included additional archive to the main archive, with couple additional files [image]
After DSC extension is applied,I see my additional archive in DSC dirrectory
[image]

My question is, how to obtain that path **C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.83.5\DSCWork\IISInstall.0** for future use in my DSC script? I tried to find any env variable, that contains that path? but futile.
Maybe do you guys know how to manage it? I appreciate any help. thank you all

Comment: You can use  $workingDirectory = Join-Path -Path $env:windir -ChildPath "Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.83.5\DSCWork\IISInstall.0"

Comment: I thought about that. Though I have a concern about 2.83.5\DSCWork\IISInstall.0 - I afraid that this could be not static value

Comment: You are correct that the path C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.83.5\DSCWork\IISInstall.0 may not be a static value. The version number 2.83.5 may change depending on the version of the DSC extension that is installed on the VM.

In this case, you can use the $env:PROGRAMFILES\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration environment variable to get the path to the DSC module directory.

Comment: ```c
$modulePath = Join-Path -Path $env:PROGRAMFILES -ChildPath "WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration"

$latestVersion = (Get-ChildItem $modulePath | Sort-Object Version -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Version

$workingDirectory = Join-Path -Path $modulePath -ChildPath "$latestVersion\DSCWork\IISInstall.0"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I do not have PSDesiredStateConfiguration folder under WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Comment: You can installed using below cmd:
Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -VMName <vm-name> -Name DSC -Publisher Microsoft.Powershell -ExtensionType DSC -TypeHandlerVersion 2.83 -Settings @{ "wmfVersion" = "latest" } -ProtectedSettings @{ "configurationUrlSasToken" = "<sas-token>" }

Answer (score 0):

I have created DSC extension created, .ps1 file in PowerShell and place the iis Install.ps1 script on the specified VM and it executed successfully like below:

```
$resourceGroup = 'dscVmDemo'
$vmName = 'myVM'
$storageName = 'demostorage'
#Publish the configuration script to user storage
Publish-AzVMDscConfiguration -ConfigurationPath .\iisInstall.ps1 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -StorageAccountName $storageName -force
#Set the VM to run the DSC configuration
Set-AzVMDscExtension -Version '2.80' -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMName $vmName -ArchiveStorageAccountName $storageName -ArchiveBlobName 'iisInstall.ps1.zip' -AutoUpdate -ConfigurationName 'IISInstall'
```

[image]

File uploaded automatically in storage account:

[image]

In your scenario, to obtain that path future in DSC script use `$env:TEMP` environment variable. A temporary folder with a name starts with "DSC" is created by the DSC extension in the `$env:TEMP` directory. You can save files you require for your DSC script in this folder.

```
$DSCWorkPath = Join-Path $env:TEMP "DSC" -ChildPath "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.83.5\DSCWork\IISInstall.0"
```

If you are hardcoding a specific version number or subdirectory in your DSC script values could potentially change in the future.

You can use to dynamically resolve the DSC working directory path using below script:

```
$extensionPath = $env:ProgramData + '\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\'
$versionFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $extensionPath | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending
$latestVersionFolder = $versionFolders[0].Name
$workingDirectory = Join-Path -Path $extensionPath -ChildPath ($latestVersionFolder + '\DSCWork\IISInstall.0')
```

This way, even if the version number changes, your script will automatically use the latest version available.

***Reference***:

[Desired State Configuration for Azure overview - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-overview)